# C++ Simple Consumer Producer Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a really simple C++ produer consumer threading code, except I am printing "Hello World"

What I want the following code to print is this:

*"HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld"*

```
condition_variable mcond; // the variable communicating events
mutex mmutex; // the locking mechanism

void hello()
{
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck{ mmutex }; // acquire mmutex
        mcond.wait(lck); /* do nothing */; // release lck and wait;
                                              // re-acquire lck upon wakeup
        cout << "Hello";

        lck.unlock();

   }
}

void world()
{
    while (true)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck{ mmutex }; // protect operations

        cout << "World";
        mcond.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t1{ hello };
    thread t2{ world };

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

What the code above is printing is this:

"WorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorld**Hello**WorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorld**Hello**WorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldWorldHelloWorldWorldWorldWorldWorld"

I suspect that the reason it's not printing in sync is because the world() function is releasing the lock and immediately grabbing it again before hello() has a chance to grab it.

I have no idea how to solve this issue though. How do I properly setup thread synchronization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads are by nature *unsynchronized* so there is no telling how long one thread will run before the other gets a chance at `CPU` time.

If you want a *strict ordering* to your output then you will have to make it happen. One way is a flag to tell each thread which word needs to be printed next:

```
// avoid using global information
struct hello_world_control
{
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    bool do_hello = true; // start with "Hello"

    // make this atomic to avoid having to lock it
    std::atomic_bool done{false};
};

void hello(hello_world_control& ctrl)
{
    // setting ctrl.done = true; will end the thread
    while(!ctrl.done)
    {
        // start a new scope for the lock
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ctrl.mtx};

            // wait until do_hello become true
            ctrl.cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return ctrl.do_hello; });

            std::cout << " Hello";
            ctrl.do_hello = false; // signal hello has been done
        }
        // when the scope ends the lock is released

        ctrl.cv.notify_one(); // tell the waiting thread
   }
}

void world(hello_world_control& ctrl)
{
    while(!ctrl.done)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ctrl.mtx};

            // wait until do_hello become false
            ctrl.cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return !ctrl.do_hello; });

            std::cout << " World";
            ctrl.do_hello = true; // signal hello now needs to happen
        }

        ctrl.cv.notify_one(); // tell the waiting thread
    }
}

int main()
{
    hello_world_control ctrl;

    // use std::ref() to pass ctrl by reference to each thread
    std::thread t1{hello, std::ref(ctrl)};
    std::thread t2{world, std::ref(ctrl)};

    // let threads run for 100 milliseconds
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    // signal threads to stop looping
    ctrl.done = true;

    // synchronize with main thread
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World Hello World Hello World
Hello World Hello World Hello World
Hello World Hello World Hello World
...
```